# Comparing the Matrix Exponential in C++ Armadillo and Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, armadillo

I've been trying to compare the speeds of the Matlab Matrix Exponential to the Armadillo C++ Matrix Exponential. I've always been told that if you want the fastest code, use C++, but the tests I performed seem to imply that the Matlab matrix exponential is *way* faster. Can someone let me know if this has been verified elsewhere, or if I'm doing something wrong?

Here is how I implemented it:

The matrices I tested were sparse and a little weird, but not particularly special. The important bit is they have dimensions 2^N by 2^N. Let I = [1 0; 0 1] be the identity matrix, and X = [0 1; 1 0] be a transposition matrix. Then, for N = 1,2,3,..., I generated the matrices,

```
A_1 = X
A_2 = kron(X,I) + kron(I,X)
A_3 = kron(X,I,I) + kron(I,X,I) + kron(I,I,X)
A_4 = kron(X,I,I,I) + kron(I,X,I,I) + kron(I,I,X,I) + kron(I,I,I,X)
```

and so on... of size 2^N by 2^N, where kron(A,B,C,...) is the Kronecker Product of matrices A,B,C,..., which can be called as kron(A,kron(B,kron(C,...))) in both Armadillo and Matlab.

I used the expmat function in Armadillo v7.300.1, and clock() to record time, and compiled on Mac in the command line with

```
c++ exptest.cpp -o exptest -larmadillo -std=c++14
```

In MatlabR2015a I used the expm function and used timeit to record time.

```
N       Matlab expm(A) (secs)       Armadillo expmat(A) (secs)
1       2.1654E-4                   4.25E-4
2       1.3655E-4                   1.09E-4
3       1.5788E-4                   1.26E-4
4       1.4571E-4                   4.17E-4
5       2.7004E-4                   6.34E-4
6       4.4781E-4                   0.003055
7       0.0012                      0.018804
8       0.0096                      0.191102
9       0.0598                      2.11156
10      0.4210                      18.5047
11      3.1949                      150.917
```

Is the Matlab matrix exponential simply much faster than the Armadillo matrix exponential, or am I doing something wrong? Also, what is the fastest computational resource for matrix exponentials?

Comment: you should turn on compiler optimizations

Comment: Could you tell me where to start with that? I don't know very much about compilers.

Comment: I dont know which one you are using, e.g for gcc the default is to do no optimization and the flag is -O2

Comment: Thanks. I thought compiler optimisation would be related, but it doesn't seem to affect the results. I'm using a gnu compiler, and even testing the flags -O1, -O2 or -O3 still leave the computation taking similar amounts of time. With just a 1024x1024 matrix of ones (I should have used this as an easier example), armadillo with optimization takes ~12 seconds, whereas Matlab takes ~0.6 seconds. I still can't believe Matlab is blowing armadillo out of the water so much though. Unless I can identify what I'm doing wrong, I'll probably have to switch to matlab

Comment: @user2520385 - make sure you also configure Armadillo to use a fast implementation of LAPACK, like [OpenBLAS](http://xianyi.github.io/OpenBLAS/) or [Intel MKL](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl/).  Matlab internally uses Intel MKL.